# Hint Property text disappears in EditText after applying @string

Tags: android, eclipse, string, android-edittext, hint

I applied a Hint property to my EditText element and the IDE says the I should hardcode an @string variable. So I go to my ***strings.xml*** and create a variable for it and then apply it to the Hint property. After saving my work, the text in the Hint property disappears. Please how can I fix this?

Comment: Show your `strings.xml` and the `EditText` from your xml.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry All. It seems my IDE needed a restart. Why that happened,I do not know but all is working fine now.